# Datatype to access pointcloud2

Tags: pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,
i am working on pobot object detection project and m totally new at Ros.
so far in project we have published pointclouds but can anyone tell me after subscribing to a pointcloud2 message through ros, how to access its data field ( WHERE THE ACTUAL DATA IS STORED)
ROS_INFO("I heard Height[%d] Width[%d] point_step[%d] row_step[%d] data[%d] ", msg->height, msg->width, msg->point_step, msg->row_step);

through this i can access height,width but what is the datatype for data field??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11556/datatype-to-access-pointcloud2/) by [youga](https://answers.ros.org/users/1191/youga/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2011-10-14

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the documentation on the [sensor_msgs::PointCloud2](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointCloud2.html) type, the 'data' member contains the actual data of the point cloud message, and the type is determined dynamically by reading the 'fields' member.

I suggest you determine what sort of data you're hoping to extract from your input point clouds, and use [pcl::fromROSMsg()](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.2.0/namespacepcl.html#abc8688665cb9e229c199344d767684f6) to convert your ros message into a [pcl point cloud](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.2.0/classpcl_1_1_point_cloud.html), at which point you can use the supplied iterators to iterate over your point cloud.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2011-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Now it seems you can do very well without the PCL library in both Python and C++.

For Python, there is the [sensor_msgs.point_cloud2](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/namespacesensor__msgs_1_1point__cloud2.html) package with the [read_points](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/namespacesensor__msgs_1_1point__cloud2.html#a0117bfe00873f9fb7a818fe5158ccfa0)  method.

For C++, you can use [sensor_msgs::PointCloud2Iterator](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/sensor_msgs/html/classsensor__msgs_1_1PointCloud2Iterator.html) to iterate the fields (like "x" for the x-coordinate, or "r" for the red color). And for creating/basic manipulation with PointCloud2 clouds, there is the [sensor_msgs::PointCloud2Modifier](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/sensor_msgs/html/classsensor__msgs_1_1PointCloud2Modifier.html#details) class, which allows you to conveniently set the fields structure, resize or clear a point cloud.

Example usage of the C++ interface (taken and simplified from ros-perception/image_pipeline):

```
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/point_cloud2_iterator.h>

using namespace sensor_msgs;

PointCloud2Ptr points_msg = boost::make_shared<PointCloud2>();
points_msg->header = ...; // TODO fill in header
points_msg->height = mat.rows; // if this is a "full 3D" pointcloud, height is 1; if this is Kinect-like pointcloud, height is the vertical resolution
points_msg->width  = mat.cols;
points_msg->is_bigendian = false;
points_msg->is_dense = false; // there may be invalid points

sensor_msgs::PointCloud2Modifier pcd_modifier(*points_msg);
// this call also resizes the data structure according to the given width, height and fields
pcd_modifier.setPointCloud2FieldsByString(2, "xyz", "rgb");

sensor_msgs::PointCloud2Iterator<float> iter_x(*points_msg, "x");
sensor_msgs::PointCloud2Iterator<float> iter_y(*points_msg, "y");
sensor_msgs::PointCloud2Iterator<float> iter_z(*points_msg, "z");
sensor_msgs::PointCloud2Iterator<uint8_t> iter_r(*points_msg, "r");
sensor_msgs::PointCloud2Iterator<uint8_t> iter_g(*points_msg, "g");
sensor_msgs::PointCloud2Iterator<uint8_t> iter_b(*points_msg, "b");

for (...) // TODO get/generate point coordinates and colors
{
  for (; iter_x != iter_x.end(); ++iter_x, ++iter_y, ++iter_z, ++iter_r, ++iter_g, ++iter_b)
  {
    // TODO fill in x, y, z, r, g, b local variables
    *iter_x = x;
    *iter_y = y;
    *iter_z = z;
    *iter_r = r;
    *iter_g = g;
    *iter_b = b;
  }
}
```

You can also apply a transform directly to PointCloud2 type using the [tf2_sensor_msgs](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/tf2_sensor_msgs/html/tf2__sensor__msgs_8h.html) (both C++ and Python interface, since at least Indigo):

```
#include <tf2_sensor_msgs/tf2_sensor_msgs.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/TransformStamped.h>

const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 cloud_in, cloud_out;
const geometry_msgs::TransformStamped transform;
// TODO load everything
tf2::doTransform (cloud_in, cloud_out, transform);
```

Or in Python:

```
from tf2_sensor_msgs.tf2_sensor_msgs import do_transform_cloud
cloud_out = do_transform_cloud(cloud_in, transform)
```

None of the codes was really tested, though I intend to use them tomorrow. If you test them and find a bug, please edit my answer. I really wonder why there aren't more tutorials for this kind of essential conversions.

---

Originally posted by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) with karma: 1366 on 2015-08-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 16

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2015-10-06**:
There is a short tutorial here for filling in a PointCloud2 message: http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/sensor_msgs/html/namespacesensor__msgs.html

**Comment by [brennocal](https://answers.ros.org/users/27653/brennocal/) on 2016-08-01**:
Hi peci1 thanks for your help, but what do you mean with "load everything" in the tf code?

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2016-08-01**:
@brennocal: You need to somehow initialize the `cloud_in` and `transform` variables. It's application-specific code you have to write.

**Comment by [skywalker](https://answers.ros.org/users/21755/skywalker/) on 2017-02-06**:
I'm having this error:

```
/home/tarik/ros_ws/src/object_seg/src/cloud_transformer.cpp:6:29: fatal error: tf2_sensor_msgs.h: No such file or directory
```

#include <tf2_sensor_msgs.h>

I've tried adding tf2_msgs to my package.xml and CMake file.

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2017-02-07**:
Add `tf2_sensor_msgs`, and not `tf2_msgs`. Also don't forget the `include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})` in your `CMakeLists.txt`.

**Comment by [skywalker](https://answers.ros.org/users/21755/skywalker/) on 2017-02-07**:
Thanks for your reply @peci1, it only worked when I add `#include <tf2_sensor_msgs/tf2_sensor_msgs.h>` to my code. I have another question tough. Is it normal that `doTransform()` takes so long? It takes around 0.44 seconds and I have pretty decent computer. Is `pcl_ros` faster?

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2017-02-08**:
@skywalker: You're right, I mistyped the `tf2_sensor_msgs` include. I've edited the answer. About the time it takes - I don't know, you have to measure it yourself. The time it takes also depends on the size of the pcl. Our 100k points get transformed pretty fast.

**Comment by [skywalker](https://answers.ros.org/users/21755/skywalker/) on 2017-02-08**:
@peci1 Can you be more specific on time it takes? My pcl is definitely under 100k points.

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2017-02-08**:
We publish the processed data on 5 Hz, so it's definitely under 200 ms.

**Comment by [skywalker](https://answers.ros.org/users/21755/skywalker/) on 2017-02-08**:
@peci1 Thanks.